# How to visualize fuzzy/approximate locations

Tags: web-mapping, cartography, visualisation

I need to visualize a mixture of accurate and fuzzy/approximate locations on a web map. The user should be able to instantly recognize approximate locations from the marker used. Are there any best practices to follow regarding the design of the location markers? I thought about using semi-transparent circles for the approximate locations, like this:

(http://dribbble.com/shots/908963-Map-Markers-PSD?list=searches&tag=map_marker)
[image]

But I would rather use icons which symbolize the "fuzzyness", because in areas with many locations in high density i suspect that to be better looking. Maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: Fuzzyness and GIS are almost opposites! Probably better to ask graphic designers.